# Angular 2, drill down table,

Tags: angular, treetableview

I want to display my data in drill down table using angular. 
My columns and rows are dynamic.

Please any one suggest me best angular component, or working example.

It will be great if you share working example

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular Data table for it. Also has features like filtering, pagination and export.

link: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

For the dynamic headers and columns you can use `ng-repeat` on the `<th>` tag and for the dynamic rows you can use `ng-repeat` on the `<tr>` tag.